# Combining these two HTML + JQuery Scripts pages into one

Tags: jquery, html, intuit-partner-platform

**Background:**

I am creating a website using Intuit Web Designs. They have, in my opinion, a very odd HTML setup which is as follows. Intuit allows me to add an HTML box (for pasting HTML code). However, the site requires me to paste anything within the `<head></head>` tags in a separate box located on the side of the page.

**What I am attempting to do:**
I have two fully functional jQuery scripts - each written in separate documents. I uploaded the html from one document into the HTML tool inside of Intuit. I then uploaded the jQuery scripts into the special headings box within Intuit. Everything worked perfectly.

Now it was time to add the second document (HTML and jQuery once again) as I wanted both documents to be running on the same page. The html uploaded fine, but as soon as I combine the second jQuery script into the first jQuery script, Chrome Console begins to inform me that JQuery Script #1 is missing files (impossible as it was just working before I added the 2nd script!). So, In conclusion, it seems as though adding the second script it made something go all out of whack.

Here are my two documents (Complete code included):

**Document #1:**

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#fancyBoxLink").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   700,
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false           
});

});     


</script>

</head>

<body>

<center>
<p>
You can
<a href="#div_table" id="fancyBoxLink">Click here to see our various things</a>
</p>
</center>

<div style="display:none" > 
<div id="div_table">

<table id="payment_options" summary="Payment Plans">
<colgroup>
<col class="poptions-odd">
<col class="poptions-even">
<col class="poptions-odd">
<col class="poptions-even"> 
    </colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" id="poptions-features">Features</th>
<th scope="col" id="poptions-startup">Startup</th>
<th scope="col" id="poptions-value">Standard</th>
<th scope="col" id="poptions-premium">Premium</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Plan one</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>Unlimited</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Document #2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>

<title>{ visibility: inherit; } The Fancybox Photo Gallery Demo #1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox.js"></script>

<link href="images/fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link href="../photoGallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

$('html').addClass('js-on');
/* Fire Fancybox */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").fancybox({
    'titleFormat':function(itemTitle, itemArray, itemIndex, itemOpts) {
                  return itemTitle + '<span> Image ' + (itemIndex + 1) + ' of ' + itemArray.length + '</span>';
                }
    });
}); 
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Prote(C#)tion Photo Gallery</h1>

<div id="gallery">
<a href="../SlideShow/mainPage.png" rel="gallery" title="Authentication Page."><img src="../SlideShow/mainPage.png" alt="" id="first"><span></span></a>
<a href="../SlideShow/importSettings.png" rel="gallery" title="Import any previously saved settings."><img src="../SlideShow/importSettings.png" alt=""></a>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**My final Question to the experts!:**
How can I combine the two headings of documents 1 and documents 2? These heading scripts need to be combined somehow, I believe this is where my problem is.

Answer (score 2):

While looking at your htmls, it seems locations of the two files in web server file system were different. For example, fancybox.js is directly referenced in the second html, while it is supposed to be versioned and in different location in the first one. And why don't you show the result html, the html you combined?

Comment: @Teasung my combined code is simply all of the heading code put together. I took out any duplicates, though, such as the Google API.